# Assigning map area to tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got the `bootstrap tooltip` working for text and for buttons, but when I try to assign a map area to it, it doesn't look like it should.

The text is there, but the bootstrap neatness is gone.

Here is the code:

```
<a>
    <img src="http://i621.photobucket.com/albums/tt296/viktorvnh/deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg" usemap="#Map"/>
<map name="Map" id="Map">
         <area shape="rect" coords="374,414,624,570" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-toggle="tooltip" title="I don't remember painting that." data-target=".modal"
</map>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/hsm6jQuk1s

*The area has no really ~position and size~, so you've got to set it... Else, the tooltip doesn't know where it should appear....*

**Css**:

```
#myarea{
  position:absolute;
  left:374px;
  width:250px;
  top:414px;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$('#myarea').tooltip();
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Now all I need to know is how to get all this into Dreamweaver. I tried putting the CSS both in my separate css.file and in the html-document like this. The JS I put in the head... but it still doesn't work!